# What does the notation "$(R, +, \cdot)$" and "$(C, +, \cdot)$" mean? (From a book on Number Systems.)

Tags: notation, algebraic-number-theory

> The number "$i$" also is as much of a mental construct and no more , as the number "$s$". The new number is defined in such a way that it not only satisfies $i^2=-1$, but when adjoined to the system of real numbers, it extends $(R, +, \cdot)$ into the bigger system $(C, +, \cdot)$ of complex numbers satisfying the associative, commutative, distributive properties already present in $(R, +, \cdot)$.

My question is regarding the notation used: $(R, +, \cdot)$ and $(C, +, \cdot)$. What do they mean?

I tried to search in the internet, but unable to find the answers.

Comment: [Mathematical structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_structure): $(\mathbb R, +, \cdot)$ is the structure with domain the *real numbers* and operations: sum and product.

Comment: E.g. $(\mathbb R,+,\cdot)$ is a *triplet* where $\mathbb R$ is the *set of real numbers* and $+,\cdot$ are the two operations (addition and multiplication), which themselves are functions from $\mathbb R^2$ (set of all pairs of real numbers) into $\mathbb R$. $+$ maps every pair $(a,b)\in\mathbb R^2$ to $a+b$, and $\cdot$ maps every pair $(a,b)\in\mathbb R^2$ to $a\cdot b$.

Comment: Two decent answers in the comment section. What is it with putting answers not in answer posts?

Comment: @StinkingBishop As Arthur says, your comment would be worth posting as an answer.

Comment: Both the answers were helpful. The first one has a link, and the second is explained well. If anyone writes the answer, I will accept it